# In Django, after extending the User model, how to add values to the new model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have extended the User model in Django with a profile model named "Account" as per 4.2 version. The Django administration panel successfully lists the "Account" model as a section, and it works wonderfully in Django Adminstration panel.

I want to set a value of "mobile_number" in Account model while the user signup. Right now I can do that manually in Django Admin Panel, but I need to update that while user signup.

models.py Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} ({self.user.first_name})"
```

admin.py Code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.models import Account
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Register your models here.
class AccountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Account
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

class CustomisedUserAdmin (UserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccountInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomisedUserAdmin) 
admin.site.register(Account)
```

views.py Code:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        mobile_number = request.POST['mobile_number']
        if password1 == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Email already registered")
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Username already registered")
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password1)
                mobile_number = user.Account.mobile_number
                user.save();
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Password not the same")
            return redirect('register')
    else:    
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

And I get error:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/create
'User' object has no attribute 'Account'
```

Comment: Please add the extended model you are using. This error log means that the 'Account' attribute on that 'user' object doesn't exist.

Comment: @Blind2k added source code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understood correctly, what you are experiencing is:

You are trying to make new account for user but Django admin firstly gets you the screen of making username and password first.

And what you want to do is:

By the time you create new account for the new user, you also want to modify the `mobile_number` at the same time, instead of manually editing the `mobile_number` after the account is actually created.

If what I understood above is correct, then I guess this is because you are extending [`UserAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/650ce967825aa192222391bfe3003c8d97e6f1d0/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L44C35-L44C35), which contains the basic logic of creating user including hashing password.

To avoid this, you may just extend the `admin.ModelAdmin` class but then you will need to include the separate logic for hashing password by yourself as saving password without being hashed into DB is critical.

Comment: Can I update the Account model after user signup?

Comment: @CaptHash I have no idea how `Account` model and `User` model are connected, but as long as you set up the relationship between two of them correctly, then you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, user has no account. In your `register` view, you never created an `Account` for the `User` (e.g. `Account.objects.create(user=user, mobile_number=mobile_number`).

That being said, there are ways to improve and clean your code. By making use of django [`forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/), in this case more specifically based on a [built in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) form:

forms.py

```py
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", 
                  "email", "password1", "password2")
```

This form will take care of all the validation (that you are doing in your view) and also offers other advantages:

views.py

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            mobile_number = request.POST.get("mobile_number")
            Account.objects.create(user=user, mobile_number=mobile_number)
            redirect("register")
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    return render(request, "register.html", {"form": form})
```

register.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;">
            <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number: </label>
            <input id="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```